# Why won't this 'if' statement run in a while loop without something else also happening in the while loop?

Tags: java, multithreading, if-statement, while-loop

I'm having a problem where an if statement is only running if there is something else happening before it in the while loop.

Here is the code I want to use:

```
public void load() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    while (true) {
        if (findGame == true) {
            System.out.println(findGame);
        }
    }
}
```

That is simplified but it shows my problem. Basically, when `findGame == true`, the if statement does not run. The reason I don't think the if statement is running is because the variable is not being printed out to the console.

I did some tests and found that the if statement ran with the following code:

```
public void load() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("foo"); // New code added
        if (findGame == true) {
            System.out.println(findGame);
        }
    }
}
```

My question is why does it work with the above code but not the first one? The only difference between the two is that the one that works has something else added to the while loop.

If it makes a difference, the code I've shown above is running in a separate thread.

Comment: Just a note, instead of `if (findGame == true)` you can simply write `if (findGame)` because `findGame` is already a boolean.

Comment: @Marv That's a good point - thanks :) I'll change that in my code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If it makes a difference, the code I've shown above is running in a separate thread.

And that's the problem. You're relying on a value set by one thread to be visible in another - and there's no such guarantee without memory barriers being involved. In your second code, the call to `println` is almost certainly responsible for creating the memory barriers required for the reading thread to "see" the value written by the writing thread. Memory models are hard, unfortunately :(

If you use [`AtomicBoolean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html) instead of just a `boolean` field, you may well find the first code works instead - but even so, a tight loop is generally a bad idea. It would be better to use a semaphore or some similar kind of signalling, so the "reading" thread could just wait (idly) until there's a change. Look into `java.util.concurrent` for classes such as [`Semaphore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) and [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html). (You can do it with just `wait` and `notify`, but it'll be simpler if you use higher-level abstractions.)

Comment: That's a brilliant answer. Thank you. I'd been stuck on this for ages and this has cleared it up. I'll look into the suggestions you have in the last paragraph as I'm fairly new to Java so don't understand what you said fully.

Comment: @KianCross: I've added a few links which should help you investigate.

Comment: Instead of the heavier-weight AtomicBoolean, you can achieve thread-safety _in this case specifically_ by using `volatile boolean`.

Comment: @Daniel: Maybe. The details of *exactly* what `volatile` does are really hairy, in my view. I try to avoid it in general - the chances of `AtomicBoolean` actually causing a performance problem (compared with the very real problem of a tight loop here) are very small.